# Как реализовать логику "radio button" для <li> элементов списка на React?

Tags: reactjs

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. 
[image: Code img]
В React компоненте `List` есть элементы `ListItem`. Нужно при событии `onClick` для `ListItem` сделать, чтобы к нажатому элементу добавлялся класс `active`. Но при этом у других элементов, этого же списка, класс `active` пропадал. То есть нужно реализовать логику как у `input type="radio"`, но для списка.

[image: example list]

Comment: Можно короче при клике получать`dataset` пункта списка (например `dataset.name`) и записывать его в состояние. и потом использовать вот так: `<li className={\` isActive && this.state.name == 'qwe' ? 'active' : 'non-active' \`}></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам придется в родительском компоненте `<List>` добавить в `state` состояние всех `<ListItem>` (какой из них **active**, а какой нет) и эти состояния передавать им через `props`-ы (каждому своё). так же обязательно нужно создать в родителе метод, который бы менял свой `state` при клике на каждый `<ListItem>` и передавать его в эти `<ListItem>`. это прием называется "всплытие состояния".
я бы написал Вам подробнее в коде, но, боюсь, у Вас только скриншот и очень неудобно. пожалуйста, напишите пример Вашего кода в письменной форме.